# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified

Tags: java, oracle, driver

I am getting
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified 
error when running my java application from eclipse. I am using Oracle version 10. classes12.jar is used for the oracle driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Please help me resolving this issue

Comment: You should give us some more information. How about the code that generates the exception? What URL are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the close vote, but if it says you have an invalid URL, you should at least show us your URL; there's no way we can help you based on this.

Comment: This similar question might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332869/invalid-oracle-url-specified-oracledatasource-makeurl. Other than that, please post the code you are trying to work with

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience... the url is jdbc:oracle:oci8@cssm

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience... the url is jdbc:oracle:oci8@cssm. The code is Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:oracle:oci8@XXXX,
          dbUSER_NAME, dbPASSWORD )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be missing a colon; as per the JDBC [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) and [developer's guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10589/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB), the syntax is:

> ```
> jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@database_specifier
> ```

So yours should be:

```
jdbc:oracle:oci8:@cssm
```