# SQLException Handling

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to run a simple Java program which fetches data from the oracle database and display it. I connected the oracle database. Here is my code:

DataHandler Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class DataHandler {
    public DataHandler() {
        super();
    }
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    //I already added the above line but still getting error.
    String userid = "scott";
    String password = "tiger"; 
    Connection conn;

    public void getDBConnection() throws SQLException{
        OracleDataSource ds;
        ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setUser(jdbcUrl);
        conn = ds.getConnection(userid,password); 
    }

    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rset;
    String query;
    String sqlString;

    public ResultSet getAllEmployees() throws SQLException{ 
        getDBConnection(); 
        stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        query = "SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY empno";
        System.out.println("\nExecuting query: " + query);
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(query); 
        return rset;
    }
}
```

and the JavaClient Class as
JavaCLient CLass:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class JavaClient {
    public JavaClient() {
        super();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        DataHandler datahandler = new DataHandler();
        ResultSet rset = datahandler.getAllEmployees();

        while (rset.next()) {
        System.out.println(rset.getInt(1) + " " +
          rset.getString(2) + " " + 
          rset.getString(3) + " " + 
          rset.getString(4));
        }
    }
}
```

I get no compilation error but while running it I get following exception error

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.makeURL(OracleDataSource.java:1277)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:185)
at student_attendence_iem.DataHandler.getDBConnection(DataHandler.java:22)
at student_attendence_iem.DataHandler.getAllEmployees(DataHandler.java:31)
at student_attendence_iem.JavaClient.main(JavaClient.java:9)
```

Process exited with exit code 1.

Please help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332869/invalid-oracle-url-specified-oracledatasource-makeurl)

Comment: I did the same thing but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set URL of your database. 
Add setURL(url) method which takes URL of database as parameter. Below is the code.

```
OracleDataSource ds;
    ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL(jdbcUrl);
```

Also, with `ds.setUser(jdbcUrl);` you are trying to **setUser** with the **URL of database** which is wrong. 
 
You don't have to setUser like this as you are already doing that in the following line of code 
 `conn = ds.getConnection(userid,password);`

Comment: @SouparnoDaripa Correction mate, she's a M'am ;)