# Spring boot oracle connection Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot application while trying to connect to the oracle database i get the following exception

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.makeURL(OracleDataSource.java:1536)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:214)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
    at com.pravaa.apex.MainController.getEmployees(MainController.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

My properties file is as below:

```
    #Oracle connection
    oracle.username=a_test_erd
    oracle.password=somepassword
    oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.def.com:1521:XE
```

My configuration class is as below:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
public class OracleConfiguration {
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

I tried the solutions provided here [Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332869/invalid-oracle-url-specified-oracledatasource-makeurl) and few other posts. Still have the same issue. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing "//"  after @ in your database url. Try with

```
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc.def.com:1521:XE
```

Comment: i tried the same oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc.def.com:1521:XE as suggested still get 

2018-04-14 21:25:11.779  INFO 14274 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 13 ms
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL